# Find the number of lines in a project with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to count the total number of lines in all of the source files of a project I have. I've tried piping `dir -r -name` into `measure-object -line`, but that just counts the number of files I have.

Does anyone have a script to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered. The way I ended up implementing this was

```
dir . -filter "*.cs" -Recurse -name | foreach{(GC $_).Count} | measure-object -sum
```

> GC  is alias for Get-Content
> dir is alias for Get-ChildItem

Comment: D'oh. And I was being so careful too. Mine works if the '-filter' is changed to '-include'. I can't say I understand why filter doesn't work.

Comment: The problem with both mine and yours was fixed with the -name parameter to the first statement - only the filename and not the path were being passed to GC. I have no idea how I ended up posting that after creating a working version earlier.

Comment: I was going to say, "copy-and-paste is your friend", but I would look like a fool if I said that now :)

Comment: FYI: with `(GC $_).Count` we get a sum including empty lines, with mesaure-object -line (see Ugot2BkidNme below) we get a sum excluding empty lines.

Answer (score 68):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.cs" -Recurse | Get-Content | Measure-Object -line
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem *.cs -Recurse will recurse the directory, but (in powershell 1.0 at least) will only show the files ending with .cs in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, because in this case, *.cs matches 'path', rather than 'filter' parameter. To fix, you can write: Get-ChildItem . *.cs -Recurse …
or Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.cs" -Recurse …

Answer (score 9):

I just expiremented a bit and found that this command does indeed measure all c# files recursively:

`Get-ChildItem -Filter *.cs -Recurse | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Word -Line -Character`

Comment: Since VS2019 crashes on the code analysis: Thank you very much

Comment: For polyglots, you can use `Get-ChildItem -Include "*.kt,*.java" ...` (or, as I just did and am kind've embarrased to admit, `-Include *.f90,*.cpp`).  not sure what the difference betwen `-Include` and `-Filter` on `Get-ChildItem` is.

Answer (score 7):

```
Get-ChildItem . -Include *.txt -Recurse | foreach {(Get-Content $_).Count}
```

Condensed down a bit with aliases:

```
GCI . -Include *.txt -Recurse | foreach{(GC $_).Count}
```

Will give results similar to this:

```
Lines Words               Characters              Property
----- -----               ----------              --------
   21
   40
   29
   15
  294
   13
   13
  107
```

EDIT: Modified to recurse through subfolders.

EDIT 2: Removed use of Measure-Object.

Answer (score 5):

dir **.txt -recurse | select Fullname,@{name="LineCount";expression={ @(get-content $_.fullname).count }}

Comment: This command isn't working for me. I get several "Select-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." errors.

Comment: I'm voting you up because I didn't know about the select command, and I'm kind of stoked about it. 

Still, though - you used `$__` instead of `$_`, you used `dir *.txt` instead of `dir -filter "*.txt"`, and your result still makes me add everything up when I'm done.

Comment: Sorry for that Dan, the editor didn't show $_ so I doubled it, thanks for voting!

Answer (score 4):

**Prints the file name and the line count:**

```
Get-ChildItem -re -in "*.cs" |
Foreach-Object { 
    $fileStats = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -line
    $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
    Write-Host "$_=$linesInFile" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed something similar this is what I came up with.

one file type:
GET-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.cs' | Get-Content | Measure-Object -line

multiple file types:
GET-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.cs','*.aspx', '*.ascx' | Get-Content | Measure-Object -line

Answer (score 0):

Count line of code (exclude blank lines) of `*.c` files recursively in a project folder

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \project-dir\src -Filter "*.c" -Recurse | ForEach-Object{(Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern .).Count} | Measure-Object -Sum


Count             : 14
Average           :
Sum               : 979
Maximum           :
Minimum           :
StandardDeviation :
Property          :
```

Answer (score -2):

Count `No. of lines` in a file inside a directory:

```
GCI . -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach{(GC $_).Count}
```

Count `SUM of lines` in a file inside a directory:

```
GCI . -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach{(GC $_).Count} | measure-object -sum
```